# How to populate specific field in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I`m new at Node JS & MongoDB so I try to build some project and I get in problem.Hope someone will be able to help me.

So what I accomplish to done is to

- Create Product
- Create Addons and populate it with Product

What I successfully did in Total is

- product info( I successfully did this because in **req.params** I send product Id )

What I need now is on Total to get also addons from specific product and I`m not able to do that because id is on addons.product not in addons._id.

**productSchema :**

```
  const product = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type:String
    },
description:{
        type:String
    } 
})
```

**AddonsSchema**

```
const addonsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    addonsName:{
        type:String
    },
    product:{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product'
    },
})

addonsSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
    this.populate({
          path: 'product',
          select: '-__v'
        });
        next();
});
```

**totalSchema**

```
const totalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    total:[{
        product:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product'
        },
        addons:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'addons'
        }
    }],
    dateCreated:{
        type:String
    }
})


totalSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
    this.populate({
          path: 'addons.product',
          select: '-__v'
        });
        next();
});
    

totalSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
    this.populate({
          path: 'addons.addons',
          select: '-__v'
        });
        next();
});
```